# How to prove that 2d support vectors are enough for Hard Margin Linear SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, unsupervised-learning

As the question states, how can I prove mathematically that 2d support vectors are enough to always be able to formulate the Maximum Margin Hyperplane in d dimensions?